# How to move a page with javascript in indesing without extend the spread?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I am new in javascript for Indesign and I have this problem.
I use this code and every time the page I want to move with script is moving but something wrong is happening. I get a spread extended - in the new order of pages, those two pages become a spread extend - The page I move plus the page AFTER become a multiple-page spread (also called an island spread). I don't want this, I want the page which I moved with the script to be single, no facing page, no extend.
Thank you very much!

```
app.scriptPreferences.measurementUnit = MeasurementUnits.POINTS;
// app.generalPreferences.pageNumbering = PageNumberingOptions.absolute;

app.scriptPreferences.enableRedraw = false;
app.layoutWindows[0].transformReferencePoint = AnchorPoint.CENTER_ANCHOR;
app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevels.NEVER_INTERACT;

var myDocument = app.documents[0];
var myPage_length = app.documents[0].pages.length
var myPages = app.documents[0].pages
var pages = app.activeDocument.pages;



var spread = app.activeDocument.spreads.everyItem()

preserveLayoutWhenShuffling = true;

myDocument.documentPreferences.allowPageShuffle = true;
spread.allowPageShuffle = true;
// myDocument.documentPreferences.allowSpreadShuffle = true;
myDocument.documentPreferences.facingPages = false;
myDocument.documentPreferences.preserveLayoutWhenShuffling = true;

/// some code
var myCounter = 0
var myAntiCounter = 1

myPages[myCounter].move(LocationOptions.AFTER, app.activeDocument.pages[myAntiCounter]);
```

Comment: I was here - http://in-tools.com/article/scripts-blog/separate-pages-script/
and no go for me.
The problem in my case is that I have multiple page on spread and I dont know how to make a one spread with one page...

Answer (score 0):

I founde the trick!
If move command use page to move the effect will be that at the end in document will be spreads with multipage, and I dont want this
The solution is to move spread instead of page
like this:

```
 app.documents[0].spreads.item(myCounter).move(LocationOptions.AFTER, app.documents[0].spreads.item(myCounter + 1));
```

Yeee :)